# Android Studio cannot resolve support library name space

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio over existing SDK with the latest Android Support Library but with a blank project open it cannot resolve this: `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle file. It must include (version may way):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
```

Comment: I checked it's there, maybe I should download the Support Repository or something.

Answer (score 0):

In your `gradle.build` include this dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'**
}
```

This may solve your problem.